# How to update graphics driver when it needs the new driver to install?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, updates, display-adapter

I tried to update my Radeon HD 7730M today, and the installer I downloaded immediately showed me this:

[image: AMD Catalyst Mobility Download]

How am I supposed to update the driver if I need the new driver to update it??

Comment: can you explain exactly what you have tried already first, how did you install the update, where did u get it from, etc.

Comment: From [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download).  And I also tried updating my Intel graphics driver -- not really sure how the two relate to each other.

Comment: Laptop graphics adapters usually require specific drivers in order to work. The ones you can download from the official AMD website are *generic* ones, and aren't compatible. What's the laptop exact model?

Comment: You can also upgrade drivers through windows update, if there is an update, you should try that as well

Comment: Did you do the Automatically Detect Hardware? If so, try downloading the installation files instead.

Comment: There might not an update to the drivers for your card.  The manufacturer should have any updates that are available.

Comment: @and31415 Dell Inspiron 7520

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Updating the drivers

Laptop graphics adapters usually require specific, customized drivers in order to work. Those you can download from the official AMD website are *generic* drivers, and aren't compatible.

All drivers can be found in the official [Dell support page](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/product/inspiron-15r-se-7520). As for the graphic card (i.e. AMD Radeon HD 7730M), latest driver version is **8.951.9.1000** right now. You can find it under the **Video** category.

Answer (score 1):

The message you are seeing is not that you need a new driver to update it!

It says that you need to obtain new driver from the notebook manufacturer i.e. Toshiba instead of downloading the driver from the graphic provider like ATI/AMD or Nvidia.

The reason for this is that the notebook manuf. buys the same chip but develop their own drivers in order to optimize power and battery usage. In many cases they also re-design the board so while the chip / chipset is the same the HW implementation may vary.